# Web Part without any title?

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to create a web part without having any title (not missing title message either). The reason I want to do it is, I want to show a message on the first page. Is there any other way to show a message? Do I need to create a new default.aspx file?

Comment: is the message going to change often?

Comment: Yes the message will be changed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set **Chrome Type** to **none** in the web part properties.